# What is the recommended way to enable a single focus for all keyboard input in Winrt?

Tags: c++-winrt

In a C++/winrt program with many xaml controls and panels I'm wondering if there is a recommended way to direct all keyboard input to one handler? And to restore that if the user temporarily uses a TextBox or other text input? I've found that handling keydown/keyup events in the MainPage works only until one uses the mouse to interact with any of the program's various Stackpanels, etc., after which it doesn't seem possible to restore focus to the MainPage. This is a program in which the keyboard is used for more than entering text in fields; it's used to trigger other events.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you are trying to implement [access keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/access-keys).

Comment: No, Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The keyboard is serving as a piano. The middle and upper rows trigger notes. I've put keydown and keyup handlers on the mainpage, but focus is always being lost during normal interaction with the mouse. Somehow I need the keyboard focus to remain on the mainpage except when entering text in a textbox or something similar.